# Can I suppress the CR/CRLF sequence in a CMD.EXE error message?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line

In the standard windows command shell, attempting to run a commmand that cannot be found results in the following error (verbatim):

```
'iamanonexistentcommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any way to suppress the CR/CRLF after `... external command,` ?

It seems independent of the size of the command window or the length of the erroneous command, at least in an interactive shell.

This is causing me problems when I attempt to capture and reformat error messages when running a command shell with `Process.Start` in the .net framework.

I end up with multiple identical messages piped in and I'd like to capture only changes from one message to the next. The problem is that CR/CRLF is interpreted as EOM when the data is available for processing through the `ErrorDataReceived` event, so the effect is that I receive multiple messages for each actual failute, one for `'iamanonexistentcommand' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` and another for `operable program or batch file.`

This feels like it was designed just to irritate me.

Comment: My guess is, this is baked somewhere in the deep dark heart of the operating system binaries. And its likely been that way since the dinosaurs roamed the earth

Comment: Your options would seemingly be **1)** send a feed back suggestion to the ms team who manages this (dont like your chances, they probably live in the basement at Redmond somewhere with nicotine stained walls and pictures of bob dylon)... **2)** find the offending library;  dll inject cmd.exe; proxy and change to taste... **3)** not do anything and build up resentment towards the world.... **4)** Or just defensively program against it **5)** change your approach

Comment: @TheGeneral I'll be building up resentment whatever happens. There are some simple algorithms for duplicate string detection, so I think I'll just post-process the entire thing. I suspect you're right that it's old, old behavior that will never change.

Comment: @TheGeneral: this is not correct, it's merely been so since the last ice age. When the dinosaurs were still around the message was `Bad command or file name`, with no line breaks -- the new message was intended as an upgrade. We may yet see improvement in the next 20 years!

Comment: On a more serious note, see if PowerShell is an option as a replacement shell. It won't run batch files on its own (it delegates that to `cmd`) but it's present out of the box in all recent versions of Windows, and can be driven programmatically from C# without having to parse text.

Comment: No wiggle room to use alternate shells etc. unfortunately - a fairly large existing user base and a long process to get any change like that into play.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to see if it meets your needs--it shows how to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` with exception handling and seems to avoid the issue that you mentioned. It's been tested, but whether or not it works for your case may depend on what other program you are calling and how the other program generates output.

Additionally, if you use a fully-qualified name for the program that you want to execute (ex: C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig.exe), you can check to see if the file exists using `System.IO.File.Exists`, prior to attempting to call it using "Process".

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig.exe))
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: Filename doesn't exist.");

    //ToDo: add desired code here

}
```

Create a class (name: Helper)

Add the following using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Create two events to allow data to be sent to subscribers.

```
//delegates
public delegate void EventHandlerProcessErrorReceived(object sender, string data);
public delegate void EventHandlerProcessOutputReceived(object sender, string data);

//event that subscribers can subscribe to
public event EventHandlerProcessErrorReceived ProcessErrorReceived;
public event EventHandlerProcessOutputReceived ProcessOutputReceived;
```

Create two methods that we can call to pass data to subscribers:

- OnErrorReceived - raised when error messages are received
- OnOutputReceived - raised when standard output messages are received

Each method checks if there are any subscribers, and if any data exists. If so, the event is raised.

```
private void OnErrorReceived(string data)
{
    //only raise event if there are subscribers and actual data exists
    if (ProcessErrorReceived != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        //raise event
        ProcessErrorReceived(this, data);
    }
}

private void OnOutputReceived(string data)
{
    //only raise event if there are subscribers and actual data exists
    if (ProcessOutputReceived != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
        //raise event
        ProcessOutputReceived(this, data);
    }
}
```

Create method that calls System.Diagnostics.Process (name: RunCmd)

**RunCmd**

```
public void RunCmd(string exePath, string arguments = null, Dictionary<string, string> environmentVarDict = null)
{
    string errMsg = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(exePath))
        {
            errMsg = "Error: fullyQualifiedExePath not specified";

            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + errMsg);
            OnErrorReceived(errMsg); //raise event

            return;
        }

        //create new instance
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, arguments);

        //add environment variables, if specified
        if (environmentVarDict != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in environmentVarDict)
            {
                //add environment variable
                startInfo.EnvironmentVariables[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
            }
        }

        startInfo.Arguments = arguments; //arguments
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //don't create a window
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard error
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if true, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'

        //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        if (exePath.Contains("\\"))
        {
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
        }

        using (Process p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
        {
            //subscribe to event and add event handler code
            p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    //ToDo: add desired code 
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
                    OnErrorReceived(errMsg); //raise event
                }
            };

            //subscribe to event and add event handler code
            p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                {
                    //ToDo: add desired code
                    //Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
                    OnOutputReceived(e.Data); //raise event
                }
            };

            p.Start(); //start

            p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
            p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

            //waits until the process is finished before continuing
            p.WaitForExit();

        }
    }
    catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
    {
        errMsg = "Error (Win32Exception): " + ex.Message;
        //Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);
        OnErrorReceived(errMsg);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        errMsg = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        //Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);
        OnErrorReceived(errMsg);
    }
    
}
```

**Helper.cs** (complete code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ProcessUsage
{
    public class Helper
    {
        //delegates
        public delegate void EventHandlerProcessErrorReceived(object sender, string data);
        public delegate void EventHandlerProcessOutputReceived(object sender, string data);

        //event that subscribers can subscribe to
        public event EventHandlerProcessErrorReceived ProcessErrorReceived;
        public event EventHandlerProcessOutputReceived ProcessOutputReceived;

        private void OnErrorReceived(string data)
        {
            //only raise event if there are subscribers and actual data exists
            if (ProcessErrorReceived != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                //raise event
                ProcessErrorReceived(this, data);
            }
        }

        private void OnOutputReceived(string data)
        {
            //only raise event if there are subscribers and actual data exists
            if (ProcessOutputReceived != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                //raise event
                ProcessOutputReceived(this, data);
            }
        }

        public void RunCmd(string exePath, string arguments = null, Dictionary<string, string> environmentVarDict = null)
        {
            string errMsg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(exePath))
                {
                    errMsg = "Error: fullyQualifiedExePath not specified";

                    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + errMsg);
                    OnErrorReceived(errMsg); //raise event

                    return;
                }

                //create new instance
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, arguments);

                //add environment variables, if specified
                if (environmentVarDict != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in environmentVarDict)
                    {
                        //add environment variable
                        startInfo.EnvironmentVariables[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                    }
                }

                startInfo.Arguments = arguments; //arguments

                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //don't create a window

                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard error
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output

                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;

                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if true, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'

                //startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

                if (exePath.Contains("\\"))
                {
                    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
                }

                using (Process p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
                {
                    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
                    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            //ToDo: add desired code 
                            //Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
                            OnErrorReceived(errMsg); //raise event
                        }
                    };

                    //subscribe to event and add event handler code
                    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            //ToDo: add desired code
                            //Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
                            OnOutputReceived(e.Data); //raise event
                        }
                    };

                    p.Start(); //start

                    p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
                    p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

                    //waits until the process is finished before continuing
                    p.WaitForExit();

                }
            }
            catch(System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
            {
                errMsg = "Error (Win32Exception): " + ex.Message;
                //Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);
                OnErrorReceived(errMsg);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errMsg = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                //Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);
                OnErrorReceived(errMsg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
Helper helper = new Helper();

//subscribe to event and add event handler
helper.ProcessErrorReceived += (s, data ) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("helper.ProcessErrorReceived: " + data);
};

//subscribe to event and add event handler
helper.ProcessOutputReceived += (s, data) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("helper.ProcessOutputReceived: " + data);
};
```

**Example 1**:

```
helper.RunCmd("test");
```

**Example 2**:

```
helper.RunCmd("ipconfig", "/all");
```

**Example 3**:

```
helper.RunCmd(@"C:\Windows\system32\ipconfig.exe", "/all");
```

**Example 4**:

```
Dictionary<string, string> environmentVarsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
environmentVarsDict.Add("environmentVar1", "myValue1");
environmentVarsDict.Add("environmentVar2", "myValue2");

helper.RunCmd("test123", "/c", environmentVarsDict);
```

Comment: Thanks for the considered answer, but we're already managing the process itself almost identically to your sample code.

As per the OP, the problem is very specifically that the single error response captured (by the OnErrorReceived function in your example) is presented as two separate events because of the embeddd CRLF in the single error message.

There isn't any wiggle room to use alternate shells unfortunately, so post-processing the entire captured error output to remove duplicates is my only option.

Comment: @mrseank: Because I catch `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`, the error you posted (`...is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`) never occurs. Instead, the following message occurs: `Error (Win32Exception): The system cannot find the file specified` - which is all on a single line