# C# Running exe through process, how to hide window

Tags: c#, process

Im running an exe through process in my c# program, i want the process to be completely invisible without the console of it popping up.

This is my code

```
Process process2 = new Process();
                process2.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                process2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process2.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                process2 = Process.Start(path3);
```

even with this code the console window still opens and shows, any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Using

`UseShellExecute = false; CreateNoWindow = true;`

Should hide the process although it depends on the path in which you are opening, if the process has a force show

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
private void RunCmd(string exePath, string arguments = null)
{
    //create new instance
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, arguments);
    startInfo.Arguments = arguments; //arguments
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //don't create a window
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard error
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if true, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

    //create new instance
    using (Process p = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.Start(); //start

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();

    }
}
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68208059/can-i-suppress-the-cr-crlf-sequence-in-a-cmd-exe-error-message/68215903#68215903).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by renaming the window instead ty for all your help