# Standard output does not print date and time for each line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, logging, cmd

I currently have a standard output process that executes a CMD command in my console application and prints the output to the log file.

**The issue?**

It would only print out the current date and time once before printing out the output.

*Example - From log .txt file*

[image]

**What do I want to achieve?**

*Example*

[image]

**Current Code**

```
static readonly string logPath = (@"C:\Temp\Test.txt");

        public static void Main()
        {

            StreamWriter logFile = new(logPath, append: true);

            var proccess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                { 
                    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                    Arguments = "/c tsm start",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true
                }
            };
            proccess.Start();

            while (!proccess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string output = proccess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if (output.Contains("successfully executed"))
                {
                    logFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + output);
                }
        }
```

Comment: The output.Contains("successfully executed") means if any of the output /contains/ that string "successfully executed" from the CMD output '/c tsm start' (not equal) it will print the date and time + the entire output. The code you see is the actual code and works perfectly, I am trying to add the DateTime to each line.

Comment: The following may be helpdul: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429665/c-sharp-running-exe-through-process-how-to-hide-window/68429794#68429794

Comment: Please post text as such (properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)!) rather than as images!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the output and write it line by line.

```
if (output.Contains("successfully executed"))
{
    var lines = output.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        logFile.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + line);
    }
}
```