# How do you open nmap and scan common ports with C#

Tags: c#, nmap

I am trying to open nmap and scan common ports but the issue is when the scan is complete nmap closes and doesn't give you a chance to look at the results
and it opens 2 nmap.exes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string IP = ip.Text;                     
            new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    FileName = "nmap.exe",
                    Arguments = "--top-ports 20 " + IP
                }
            }.Start();
            string arguments = "--top-ports 20 " + IP;
            Process.Start("nmap.exe", arguments);
        }
```

Comment: It runs nmap twice because you’re starting it twice

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429665/c-sharp-running-exe-through-process-how-to-hide-window/68429794#68429794